# User.IsInRole vs Roles.IsUserInRole in AuthenticateRequest

Tags: asp.net-membership, membership, membership-provider, roleprovider

HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole is ***not*** available in AuthenticateRequest; however, Roles.IsUserInRole is available.

Is it because new GenericPrincipal is assigned to HttpContext.Current.User after AuthenticateRequest? Could someone explain me about it? Appreciate your help!

```
void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        // Return False
        bool result1 = HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Administrators");

        // Return True
        bool result2 = Roles.IsUserInRole("Administrators");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you should be subscribing to `AuthorizeRequest` instead. This event comes after `AuthenticateRequest`, so the identity of the principal has been established.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx